# Getting "PerfectSeparationError:" when using the statsmodels.GLM( ) class for Logistic Regression

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I am trying to fit a Logistic Regression model using the `GLM` class from `statsmodels` library. I have a toy dataset with 1250 records in total and 8 Independent variable.

```
Predictor: ['Year', 'Lag1', 'Lag2', 'Lag3', 'Lag4', 'Lag5', 'Volume', 'Today']
train dataset shape: (1000, 9)    # 9 predictors including Intercept
Test dataset shape : (250, 9)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1250 entries, 0 to 1249
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   Year       1250 non-null   int64  
 1   Lag1       1250 non-null   float64
 2   Lag2       1250 non-null   float64
 3   Lag3       1250 non-null   float64
 4   Lag4       1250 non-null   float64
 5   Lag5       1250 non-null   float64
 6   Volume     1250 non-null   float64
 7   Today      1250 non-null   float64
 8   Direction  1250 non-null   object 
dtypes: float64(7), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 88.0+ KB
```

Here is my code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncode

X4 = df.drop(labels = ['Direction'], axis = 1)
y4 = df['Direction'].copy()

X4_train, X4_test, y4_train, y4_test = train_test_split(X4, y4, stratify = y4, train_size = 0.8)

X4_train = sm.add_constant(X4_train, prepend = True)  # adding an intercept manually to training data
X4_test = sm.add_constant(X4_test, prepend = True)    # adding an intercept manually to test data

OE4 = OrdinalEncoder()

y4_train = OE4.fit_transform(np.asarray(y4_train).reshape(-1,1)).ravel()
y4_test = OE4.transform(np.asarray(y4_test).reshape(-1,1)).ravel()

glm4 = sm.GLM(endog = y4_train, exog = X4_train, family = sm.families.Binomial())
glm4_result = glm4.fit()
glm4_result.summary()
```

After splitting into training and test, when I fit the model I'm getting the below error along with a **RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide**

Here is the entire error:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\families\family.py:894: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  n_endog_mu = self._clean((1. - endog) / (1. - mu))
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\families\links.py:188: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  t = np.exp(-z)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\families\family.py:893: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  endog_mu = self._clean(endog / mu)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PerfectSeparationError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-166-66b45a65beec> in <module>
      2 
      3 glm4 = sm.GLM(endog = y4_train, exog = X4_train[['Lag1', 'Lag2', 'Lag3', 'Lag4', 'Lag5', 'Volume', 'Today']], family = sm.families.Binomial())
----> 4 glm4_result = glm4.fit()
      5 glm4_result.summary()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py in fit(self, start_params, maxiter, method, tol, scale, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t, full_output, disp, max_start_irls, **kwargs)
   1025             return self._fit_irls(start_params=start_params, maxiter=maxiter,
   1026                                   tol=tol, scale=scale, cov_type=cov_type,
-> 1027                                   cov_kwds=cov_kwds, use_t=use_t, **kwargs)
   1028         else:
   1029             self._optim_hessian = kwargs.get('optim_hessian')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py in _fit_irls(self, start_params, maxiter, tol, scale, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t, **kwargs)
   1172             if endog.squeeze().ndim == 1 and np.allclose(mu - endog, 0):
   1173                 msg = "Perfect separation detected, results not available"
-> 1174                 raise PerfectSeparationError(msg)
   1175             converged = _check_convergence(criterion, iteration + 1, atol,
   1176                                            rtol)

PerfectSeparationError: Perfect separation detected, results not available
```

However, I can see that if I only keep **6 predictors** or less then fit() method works and I can then see the summary( ), but If I exceed more than six then I will keep getting this "PerfectSeperationError"!

So, does this class statsmodels.GLM() only accepts just 6 predictors, In my view it must not be the case otherwise what's the use of this class!! I'm probably sure of making some mistake in my code, which I am not able to find out, hence could someone please help me do the required correction?[image]

[image]

Comment: If the today field is a date and it's one record per date, there is no way to not have them be totally separated.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono predictor 'Today' doesn't contain datetime records...its of type ```float64```

Comment: What does it represent, the Today feature?

Comment: Percentage returns

Comment: Okay, I mean Perfect Separation happens when all or nearly all your values in one predictor are associated with only one outcome. When this is the case you can't find a solution for the predictor coefficient. You should cross tab your predictors and outcomes to find the one with zero observations.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono Ah, yes I can see that its something wrong with predictor 'Today', If I keep it in place and remove any other 1or 2 predictors I am getting the same error !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222320/discussion-between-adarsh-namdev-and-dejavusansmono).